# how to access each element of a query variable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

i'm new in C# and WPF. Suppose i have a table. This table has two fields: "firstName" and "birthDate". I write a query to fetch "birth day" records, then i want to show it on a datagrid. but before this, i want to change "Gregorian date" to "jalali date" with a function.

in C# :

```
var searchQueryOfDateAndTime = (from b in FaceDB.tblCameras
                                        join c in FaceDB.tblTraffics
                                       on b.Camera_Id equals c.Camera_Id
                                       join a in FaceDB.tblknownPeoples
                                       on c.IdNumber equals a.IdNumber

                                       where
                                       (
                                           string.Compare(c.EntryDate.ToString(), miladiFromDate.ToString()) >= 0
                                           &&
                                           string.Compare(c.EntryDate.ToString(), miladiToDate.ToString()) <= 0
                                       )
                                       where
                                       (
                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(timFromHour.Text.ToString())
                                           ||
                                           string.Compare(c.EntryTime.ToString(), timFromHour.Text.ToString()) >= 0
                                           &&
                                           string.IsNullOrEmpty(timToHour.Text.ToString())
                                           ||
                                           string.Compare(c.ExitTime.ToString(), timToHour.Text.ToString()) <= 0
                                       )

                                       select new { a.Name, a.Family, EntryDate = Georgian2Jalali(c.EntryDate), c.EntryTime, a.Occupation, ExitDate = Georgian2Jalali(c.ExitDate), c.ExitTime, b.Camera_Name, c.PicAddress, a.FirstPicAddress, c.IdNumber, c.Camera_Id }).ToList();

        dgvFinalyReport.ItemsSource = searchQueryOfDateAndTime;
```

and in WPF:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvFinalyReport" Height="431" Width="630" Canvas.Left="273" Canvas.Top="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="firstname" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding Family}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Entry date" Binding="{Binding EntryDate}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="entry time" Binding="{Binding EntryTime}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="exit date" Binding="{Binding ExitDate}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="exit time" Binding="{Binding ExitTime}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="occupation" Binding="{Binding Occupation}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cam_Name" Binding="{Binding Camera_Name}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="getface" Binding="{Binding PicAddress}" Width="78" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="first face" Binding="{Binding FirstPicAddress}" Width="78" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other alternative is to create a converter that takes the Gregorian date and converts it to the Jalali date:

```
public class JalaliDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       // Gregorian to Jalali conversion code

       return jalaliaDate;
    }

    public ConvertBack((object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Jalali to Gregorian conversion code

        return gregorianDate;
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you have:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Birth Day"
                    Binding="{Binding birthDate, Converter={StaticResource JalaliDateConverter}}"
                    Width="80" />
```

See [here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) for a fuller tutorial on converters.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what are the value , targetType and parameter ? Furthermore how do i use this class with "select" command?

Comment: @Saeid - these parameters are the standard ones for the converts. `value` is the value passed in - in the Convert case the Gregorian date, in the ConvertBack case the Jalali date. `parameter` will be null as you haven't specified one (you don't need it). `targetType` is the type that is returned.

Comment: You don't use it with the select command. You add the converter class to your project and the converter to your XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Since `new {}` creates a read-only anonymous type, you can't loop through query and update the values of birthdate. Instead, you can change the value directly:

```
var query = from f in mydb.mytbl.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    f.firstName,
    BirthDate = ConvertToJalali(f.BirthDate)
};

private DateTime ConvertToJalali(DateTime dt)
{
 // your implementation here
}
```

Note: Be aware of using `AsEnumerable()` as it drags all the records from the database into memory, but in your specific case it doesn't make any difference because you don't have any where clause.

Comment: thanks a lot but i have a bug with your suggestion. VS2015 get me this exception message: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Georgian2Jalali(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Saeid Since you don't have a where clause, you can add `AsEnumerable()` to do in memory creation of objects, so replace `mydb.mytbl` with `mydb.mytbl.AsEnumerable()`. Not that we don't usually do this in case we have a filtering conditions, but in the example you specified it makes no difference.

Comment: but in real i have some where clause in my real code. Since we have limitation for characters in "comment", I've edited above code.

regards